# simple concept confusion in R around outliers and Grubbs test

Tags: r, outliers, chi-squared-test, p-value

I did two tests in R, chi-square and Grubbs'

Here is the code:

```
library(outliers)
d <- read.csv('output9.csv')
bytes <- d$Bytes
d $Bytes <- as.numeric (d $Bytes)
test1 <- chisq.out.test(d$Bytes, variance = var(d$Bytes))
print (test1)
```

Grubbs:

```
library(sos);
library(outliers);
d <- read.csv('output9.csv')
bytes <- d$Bytes
bytes <- as.numeric (d$Bytes)
grubbs.test(bytes)
```

Output for chi-square:

```
X-squared = 2.3228, p value = 0.126
Alternative hypthesis: lowest value 1 is an outlier
```

Output for Grubbs:

```
data: bytes
G = 3.166, U = 0.9889, p value = 1
```

1) Does the p value mean comparison between two data? I used bytes column in my data to do test. What does the p value mean? since I'm not comparing to anything else

2)For Grubbs test, what do G and U value mean? What is the relationship between those two values?

Comment: That is a question that is answered in just about any introductory statistics textbook, or in tons of webpage/youtube clips on the net. Your question isn't really about programming and possibly belongs on StatsExchange

Comment: This is not a programming question. I suggest a trip to the library to get a statistics textbook.

Comment: @Roland can you please write an answer? I'm just a beginner

Comment: The way to becoming an expert is research and studying. I highly recommend these.

Comment: @Roland I couldn't find what the U value stand for? Can you write an answer on that please?

Comment: @ekstroem hey sir can you please tell me what the U value stand for? I can't find that one?

Comment: Read `help("grubbs.test")`. It explains it and provides a reference.